# retrieve json data using GET in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, get, http-request

I've got some data stored in a nosql database that I'm able to see in when accessing localhost:3000/countries.

I'm trying to use this factory in order to get the data which is in json.

```
.factory('countries', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {


    var countries = {
                get: function() {
                    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: '/countries'
                        }).then(function(response) {

                            resolve(response.data);
                        }, function(error) {

                            reject(error);
                        });
                    });
                };

   return countries;
    }
]);
```

And then I'm attempting to use this controller to send that data to the appropriate url to be displayed but it isn't working as I expected it to.

```
.controller('CountriesCtrl', function($scope, countries) {
    console.log(countries);
    countries.get(function(countries) {
        $scope.countries = countries;
    });
})
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You need to inject your newly-created factory service, i.e. _devices_

Comment: If you use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. In the resolve function use the service as described by @Alex, then inside of the controller you'll only have to inject the name of the resolve and the data is ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use currently in my project that uses Mongodb

```
cmsApp.factory("tasks", ["$resource", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/tasks/", {}, {
    save: {
      method: 'POST',
      isArray: true
    },
    'delete': {
      method: 'DELETE',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
}]);
```

Then in the Controller(make sure to inject it to controller!):

```
$scope.tasks = tasks.query();
```

.query() selects all of the data while .get() gets on by Id

Answer (score 0):

You should inject your factory into your controller, something like this:

```
.controller('CountriesCtrl', function($scope, devices) {
    console.log(countries);
    countries.get(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inject service 'devices' instead of it's internal variable 'countries'.

```
.controller('CountriesCtrl', function($scope, devices) {
    console.log(devices);
    devices.get().then(function(countries) {
        $scope.countries = countries;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that should have been countries. Error when I was posting.

Comment: Ok, have you tried my code snippet with 'countries' instead of 'devices'? What logs or result do you see and what is expected?